# What Is The Cause Of This URLOpen Error

Tags: python, windows, debugging, urllib2

My Python code downloads a file from our website. The code fails to download the file on certain clients computers. I cant for the life of me figure out why the file fails to download when the script runs on certain computers but works on others.

The error that occurs on certain computers is:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

The clients confirm they are connected to the internet and they can successfully download the same file(same url) through a web browser. Its incredibly weird that the script works on some computers and not on others, that they are connected to the internet but cannot download the file and that they can download the file through a browser but not through my script? Maybe the cause it that they are not an admin user?

**What can cause this kind of error?**

My simple code:

```
try:

    source_buffer = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
    source_code = source_buffer.read()
    source_buffer.close()
    return source_code

except Exception, e:
    print e
```

**PS:** Do you think this is a proxy error? If it is can you explain what exactly is going wrong? Proxies have always confused me - well I understand when using a proxy all http, https, ftp requests go through a proxy computer (intermediary) before going out to the internet but I dont understand how this error can be caused from a proxy? Whats going wrong? Whats occurring?

Comment: Consider using `requests` library, it is much easier to use.

Comment: Is there any difference between the computers that work and those that don't? .e.g different OS, different version of Python etc.

Comment: @mhawke I have confirmed that they are using Windows 7 OS, same version of python 2.7. One thing I cannot determine is their network setup (if they use a proxy, etc.) because they are not the most technical users and wouldn't know.

Answer (score 1):

It could be proxy, or looking at the error message, it could also be that local/personal firewall settings are blocking the outgoing requests from your application, or responses from the server from reaching your application. Local firewall settings could easily vary between computers, and this might account for the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do think that because they can download the file using a web browser (but cant inside my script) that that means its not the proxy? Because the proxy would also disallow the browser to download it also?

Comment: If its the firewall blocking the out/in requests. Is there anything programmatic I can do? - thats not hacking ofcourse. Or is my only solution to contact the company and ask their IT department to add my script &/or url to an exclusion list?

Comment: It may be a proxy issue, but it could be something else such as a firewall. Some firewalls let you grant permission on a per-application basis, so it could be that the browser is allowed (possibly indirectly via a proxy), but your app is not. Rather than guessing, you need to determine the cause of the problem first. To do that requires that you ask your users the right questions, or get physical or [remote](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/connect-using-remote-desktop-connection#connect-using-remote-desktop-connection=windows-7) access to one of the affected computers.

Comment: Another strategy is to try and replicate the problem in your development environment. Have you tried testing with a proxy and/or firewall, or any other ideas that you have had?